# Export SQL Script from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy with ORM and DeclarativeMeta to connect to my Database.

Is there a way to generate or export a .sql file that contains all the Create Tables Commands?

Thank you!

I tried to get that information from my Meta Object or even from my SQLAlchemy Engine but they don't hold information like that.

Even the Meta.metadate._create_all() does not return a string or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answers in the documentation of sqlalchemy.

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
print(CreateTable(my_mysql_table).compile(mysql_engine))

CREATE TABLE my_table (
id INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

[SQLAlchemy Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#reflecting-with-database-agnostic-types)!